# Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open &&& HTTP Method not supported by the mapped source

Tags: appium, robotframework

We have 2 problems , (1) [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
(2) WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource .

i dont know what is this because i searched for the problem i dont know what i must to do , i check the versions for appium and installed exactly respect to toturials, i asked chatGPT i searched along today became 4 dayes nearly ....... see images to undarstand my codes

```
*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary
 

*** Test Cases ***
AppTest  
   Open Application             http://localhost:4723/wd/hub          
...                             automationName=UiAutomator2    
...                             platformName=Android 
...                             deviceName=e731c27b                           #My Device Name
...                             autoGrantPermissions=true
...                             appPackage=chat21.android.demo
...                             appActivity=chat21.android.demo.SplashActivity
...                             platformVersion=13
```

---

----- My appium version 2.0.1       i used befor  2.1.3 latest  same problem accured
----- NPM version       10.0.0

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYwHA.png)

[Error in Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS7gl.png)